# VB.NET form connected to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I'm really new to vb.net and database and I have been researching and practicing on the subject for 2 days.

I have to make a form on vb.net, once filled, all the information will be transferred to a database. This form will be used and filled many times, so each time its filled, ill be have a new record in the table.

I found an online tutorial that helps me do that with MS Access, it worked but it was very complicated and had lots of bugs.

I just need the steps to follow, what to search for, to be able to continue my work.

So far, I finished the form on vb.net

The next step is to create the database using SQL Server, and connect it to the form. Is there any way to do this in visual studio using GUI, or do I need to fix codes and implement them?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I think your question is too broad. If you have specific issues, or specific errors, post those details.

Comment: @Mort I'm getting this error after running the app- The program '[5220] App1.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Can I suggest you put error handling `Try ... Catch` into all your methods for a start to find where this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is too broad.

This might help you though.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMOPRJwR6GI

Im at work and cant view youtube but it looks to be about updating a database from a form.